# Algolia filter not working for object array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, algolia

In Algolia Index i have data in below format.

[image]

Now I want only records which belong to the only category which I provide.

Here is the logic which I am using to do that but I am getting an empty result.

[image]

Comment: What does the arrays contain? I haven't worked with algolia before, but I know arrays in elasticsearch are just a "bag of values", in which you cannot specify an index. So unless algolia makes it possible to use the key, I guess you should filter on another value

Comment: @ErikvandeVen Array contains key and value and a key is category id in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely 3 years late, but the syntax for querying arrays is different than other values: [arrays expect colon notation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/how-to/filter-arrays/#using-the-api-1).  Try applying the following instead and it should get hits:

```
['filters' => 'category:1 OR category:2']
```

You'll also need to configure `category` as a [facet filter](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/how-to/filter-arrays/#configuring-attributesforfaceting-at-indexing-time).